# What is the proper balance between halacha and social life?

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy

I guess the question that I'm going to ask is an aspect of a much broader question on the tension between halacha and openness and I'm not even sure whether the question is halachic or hashkafic ... But anyway ...
Let's say, Reuven is a single guy, who lives in a small apartment and he considers to elevate his level of kashrut. Let's also assume that Reuven has a couple of friends who are married and have children which means, that practically he can not invite them for a shabbos meal to his house and the only way they can eat together, is for him to visit them at their house. Let's also assume that these friends are not keeping that level of kashrut that he is considering. Therefore Reuven understands that the price for elevating his level of kashrut would be reducing the connection to some of his good friends, or, in more general terms, limiting his social life. What would be the true way to look at this dilemma from the perspective of the Torah ? Here are some of the answers that I consider:

1. The ratzon Hashem is primarily expressed through the halacha. Therefore, in order to observe the halachot of kashrut more properly, Reuven should be willing to pay the cost of practicing friendships/ social life in a more limited way.
2. The ratzon Hashem is not limited to halacha but Hashem equally appreciates the value of friendship/ social life. Therefore the proper balance between these 2 aspects is a question of personal preference.
3. Hashem has such a high appreciation for certain aspects of a persons life, such as friendships, that he does not want Reuven to limit them for the sake of fulfilling halacha more properly.

Of course there might be also other practical solutions to the described dilemma (e.g. Reuven could come to his friends with his own food – a solution that is rather unpractical and moreover, might make them feel a bit uncomfortable) but at this point I’m not considering them, because the question is designed to illustrate a more general dilemma. I realize that the proposed answers sound rather simplistic and maybe it would be more  proper to express them in a more sophisticated way. I also assume that dozens of essays have been written on this dilemma by various jewish thinkers since it is so fundamental and, probably, is relevant to most orthodox jews. Therefore, I would also appreciate both personal opinions and literature suggestions on the dilemma described above.

Comment: Why can't you go out to a kosher restaurant? Why can't you order kosher food? Why can't you cook together (using kosher ingredients and utensils), which itself is a hobby for many?

Comment: I don't think you will ever find that keeping real *mitzvos* causes you to lose.